# Determinant of the linear transformation $S: \mathbb{K}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ such that $S(X) \mapsto X^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $n \geq 1$.

Let $S: \mathbb{K}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ such that $S(X) \mapsto X^t$ be a linear transformation.

What is the determinant of $S$?

I know that $S$ has $n^2$ base vectors, which are the matrices $E_{ij}$, where every entry is $0$ except of the entry $ij$, which is $1$.

But I have no idea how to calculate the determinant of $S$. I tried to calculate the "matrix" of $S$, but with no success.

Comment: There is one type error:
K is a field*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb K^{n\times n}$ has an eigenbasis consisting of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ symmetric matrices and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ skew-symmetric matrices. Each symmetric matrix is an eigenvector of $S$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, while each skew-symmetric matrix is an eigenvector of $S$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$. Therefore $\det(S)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix for $S$ has a very simple form. Assume the basis is $E_{11},...,E_{nn},E_{12},E_{21},E_{13},E_{31},...,E_{(n-1)n},E_{n(n-1)}$ then the matrix for $S$ with respect to this basis is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
I_n & 0\\
0 & P_{n^2-n}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$ and $P_{n^2-n}$ is a permutation matrix of order $n^2-n$ that swaps $E_{ij}$ and $E_{ji}$.
$P_{n^2-n}$ has a block structure too (an example in this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440006/determinant-of-the-linear-transformation-s-mathbbkn-times-n-to-mathbb/4440027#comment9295554_4440027)) Hence the determinant is easily computed as $(-1)^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$.

Comment: This is not correct. E.g. when $n=3$, the matrix of $S$ with respect to the basis $\{E_{11},E_{22},E_{33},E_{12},E_{21},E_{13},E_{31},E_{23},E_{32}\}$ is $I_3\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. Therefore $\det(S)=(-1)^3=-1$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes you are right, it depends on the order. Thanks